# Implementing "copy down" feature, similar to Excel, in inline editable kendo grid

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to implement the "copy down" feature in an inline editable kendo grid, somewhat like in Excel. The objective would be to enter values in some cells in the first row of my grid, to select these cells, and with a contextual menu have a shortcut to "copy these values on every row of my grid". So that users can type values only once instead of typing the same value on every row of the grid.

I'd like to know if it's possible to create such functionality in GridView.

I already searched lots for this but was unable to find any solutions yet.

I found this thread https://www.telerik.com/forums/gridview-copy-down-feature-a-bit-like-in-excel#n3BDNFP2KUOsha-IVsvO7w and it's showing use `Extended`SelectionMode but I'm unable to find any solutions or any demo for this.

My kendo grid is binding using JSON ajax.

Please help me.

Comment: I had done something similar when I needed but I did it completely custom. Custom selector checkboxes and add them in the grid datasource when the button was pressed. After that I saved the entire grid with the batch option. Is that something that would suit you?

Comment: thanks for your reply but how i can i add custom check boxes for each columns?is that make sense?

Comment: I added custom checkboxes with clienttemplate and on every check of the checkboxes I hold on in javascript objects the selected id's. When the user presses the button I go and get the selected rows from the grid datasource and add them as new. It is a custom-javascript solution because for many things I found the "kendo-way" quite complicated.

Comment: Well actually I needed the custom checkboxes for a series of things I had to do. You might not need that. You could just get the selected objects from the default selection mode of kendo grid. You would just need the right way to get the kendo grid selected rows. Than would probably make it a lot easier.

Comment: thanks for your reply i need to replace more than one column value with desired value not whole row.